# Paypal IPN question (integrating with backend processes)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am using the Paypal standard to integrate to my website, using HTML form fields.

I have enabled IPN notifications on my (sandbox) account, and the Paypal server is able to successfully call my website, with IPN data.

I want to be able to respond to the following specific events in my backend processing (i.e. using custom server side scripts):

Event                  Description
completed              payment completed successfully
subscr_eot             subscription end of term
subscr_cancelled       subscription cancelled
card_chargeback        credit card chargeback event
claim_dispute_began    claim dispute has began
claim_dispute_closed   claim dispute has been closed
refund                 A refund has been made.

I am aware that it is possibly (*some) combination of payment_status, txn_id (and possibly some other fields). There are several fields returned in the IPN data. However, the documentation does not cleanly partition the fields into those required to uniquely identify events that a user may want to listen to (such as the ones above) - at least, I was unable to do so from the documentation.

I would appreciate if someone with experience of Paypal integration could point out (i.e. map) the  events above to the fields used to identify them.

For example, the completed event will be mapped as follows:

complete => payment_status=complete

etc.

Comment: So I'm not the only one to find PayPal documentation painfully confusing? Good.

Answer (score 0):

Is Table 2. Summary of subscription variables here: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables what you are looking for?